# Is there a smarter and more important functioning way to display the products from my database in my shop in a way i can sort them later?

Tags: javascript, php, html, e-commerce, webshop

I know it is bad practice to echo `html` code but I am a beginner and I haven't found a more suitable way. Also I can sort my items by just letting the user change the `sql` query which is kind of easy (and yes it also makes me vulnerable to `sql injections`) but I'd be open to completely new suggestions or tutorials you know. My goal is to show all 43 Items in my database on my website and let the user sort them. I would also get involved with `javascript` if that's needed.

edit - I am using a local `xampp server`.

```
<? php
    foreach($json as $row) {
        echo '<div class="col-lg-4">
                < div class="trainer-item" >
                    <div class="image-thumb" >
                        <img src = "assets/images/product-6-720x480.jpg" alt = "" >
                    </div >
                    <div class="down-content" >
                        <span >
                            <sup > $ </sup > '($row[' ProductPrice ']); '
                        </span >

                        <h4 > '.($row[' ProductName ']).' </h4 >
    
                        <p > Product description</p >
    
                        <ul class="social-icons" >
                            <li ><a href = "product-details.html" > +Order </a ></li >
                        </ul >
                    </div >
                </div >
            </div > ';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write a `REST` api to return JSON items from database and call it in UI asynchronously:

```js
fetch(`http://RestApiUrl`)
        .then(function (response) {
            const json = response.json();
            for (row in json) {
                var div = document.createElement("div");
                div.setAttribute("class", "col-lg-4");

                var trainerItem = document.createElement("div");
                trainerItem.setAttribute("class", "trainer-item");

                var imageThumb = document.createElement("div");
                imageThumb.setAttribute("class", "image-thumb");

                var img = document.createElement("img");
                img.setAttribute("src", "assets/images/product-6-720x480.jpg");
                imageThumb.appendChild(img);

                var downContent = document.createElement("div");
                downContent.setAttribute("class", "down-content");

                var price = document.createElement("span");
                price.innerHTML  = `<sup>$</sup>${row.ProductPrice}`

                var name = document.createElement("h4");
                name.innerHTML  = row.ProductName
                downContent.appendChild(price);
                downContent.appendChild(name);

                trainerItem.appendChild(imageThumb);
                trainerItem.appendChild(downContent);

                div.appendChild(trainerItem);
            }
            /*Set the items to main div*/
            document.getElementById('main').innerHTML  = div;
        })
```

```html
<div id="main" class="row"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the awnser! Im sorry but i might have confused you with $json  which is not actually a json file but just a multidimensional array where each array in the json array is a row in the database does this solution still work ? or what do i have to do to make it a correct json file ?

Comment: Yes, It will work. Here I am expecting Array of objects in response.

Comment: So... I encoded the result of my query to a .json file and put in the url of the file (http://localhost/KUR/products.json) and it doesnt seem to work also im not sure what you mean by writing my own rest api

Comment: would it help if I shared the files ?